# Powershell Retrieve IO Operations for Each Process and List with Process Information

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

I'm trying to get a list of processes with heavy I/O Reads along with the associated ProductVersion. The code would look something like this:

```
$counter = "\Process*\IO Read Operations/sec"
get-counter | ? {$counter -gt 10} | gps | select name,productversion,reads
```

and the output would look something like this:

```
Name    ProductVersion    Reads
-----   --------------    -----
p1      16.1.723.2342     15.98324
p2      12.3.234.1231     11.34323
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347677.aspx)

I am using a different counter for fetching result on my system. You can draw out an analogy and use accordingly :-

```
$Proc = Get-counter "\Process(*)\% processor time"

$Proc.CounterSamples | where {$_.instanceName -ne "idle"} | where {$_.instanceName -ne "_total"} | Format-Table -auto
```

**Output:-**

```
Path                                                                   InstanceName                          CookedValue
----                                                                   ------------                          -----------
\\angshuman\process(system)\% processor time                           system                           1.54907723252374
\\angshuman\process(smss)\% processor time                             smss                                            0
\\angshuman\process(csrss#1)\% processor time                          csrss                            1.54907723252374
```

Comment: I realize that I can use Format-Table to display output; however the trick here is that I need to get counters along with process information. If I just needed the counters then your answer would be correct; however, I don't. Thanks, though.

Comment: The process information that I am looking for is ProductVersion. Please read the question fully.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom table from multiple sources you need to create an array and then pipe each variable as a new object:

```
$counter = "\Process*\IO Read Operations/sec"
$processes = gps | select id | ForEach {$_.id}
$ccounter = get-counter -listset process | get-counter -maxsamples 1 | select -expandproperty countersamples | where {$_.path -like $counter -and $_cookedvalue -eq $processes} | select cookedvalue | ForEach {$_.cookedvalue}
function Get-CounterValue ($mypid) { Code Here.... }
function GetProductVersion ($mypid) { ...code here... }
function GetProcessName ($mypid) { ...code here... }

$myresults = @()
$x = foreach ($procc in $processes) {
 $thisname = GetProcessName $procc
 $thisprod = GetProductVersion $procc
 $thisread = GetCounterValue $procc
 $robj = New-Object System.Object
 $robj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $thisname
 $robj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ProductVersion -value $thisprod
 $robj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Reads -value $thisread
 $myresults += $robj
}
$myresults | ft -auto
```